# How to save radiobutton data in MVC controller edit method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, radio-button, edit

In the Edit page, I have two radio buttons for gender, once user selected the gender Male or Female, the value should be saved in the database.

I tried all the solutions proposed, but none works.

Here is the view page:

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsMale, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="radioLeft col-sm-3">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsMale, "Male", new { @checked = true })Male
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsMale, "Female", new { @checked = false })Female
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsMale, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the Controller Edit method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit( WebUser webUser)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.Entry(webUser).State = EntityState.Modified;           
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(webUser);
    }
```

Comment: '...but none works' - *What* have you tried and what did happen when you tried them?

Comment: What do you mean by "but none works"? Can you provide us with more information on what happens when you check the radiobutton?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. When I clicked the SAVE button, it doesn't work, it shows "The value 'Female' is not valid for Sex.", why?

Comment: It sounds like whatever data field you have in your model, doesn't support that string

Comment: my model is : public Nullable<bool> IsMale { get; set; }

Comment: Even if I changed the @checked=0 or 1, it gives the same error message. My model is : public Nullable<bool> IsMale { get; set; }         I think it missing something in the Edit Method of Controller, but don't know what.... Do you have an idea please?

Answer (score 1):

Your type is `Nullable<bool>`, but you're sending either the string `"Male"` or `"Female"`. How is the modelbinder supposed to know which one means true and which means false? If you've got a `bool` type then you need to pass something boolean, for example:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsMale, true) Male
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsMale, false) Female
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The error message is gone! Thanks a lot! But I still cannot save the value of "IsMale". When submit the changes, the edit controller just jump to the "catch (DataException)", to show "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator." Do I have error in my edit controller?

Comment: public ActionResult Edit( WebUser webUser)
        {   
              try 
          { 
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(webUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
               }
            return RedirectToAction("Details"); 
           }
            catch (DataException) 
          { 
               
             ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator."); 
          }  

            return View(webUser);
          }

Comment: `DataException` is a low-level exception that means the query that was sent to SQL Server caused an error there. This is most often caused by the database schema being out of sync with what Entity Framework expects it to be. For example, if you changed the name of a column directly on SQL Server, but left everything the same in your code. It also assumes that you're either using Database First, Code First with an existing database, or you have simply disabled migrations in Code First.